# Triangular system of a matrix with Sympy and Scipy/Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sympy, linear-algebra

I've just begun teaching myself linear algebra, and I'm trying to teach myself some basic Python modules alongside it. I've decided to learn the linear algebra components of Scipy and Numpy, along with some Sympy, if I can.

I have encountered the following exercise:

[image: matrix]

I've solved the first step of that manually (I believe):

[image: solution]

And I'd like to solve this using Numpy and/or Scipy, as well as Sympy. I've spent some time today trying to figure out what structures to use to solve this (Numpy array, obviously, and then the Sympy Matrix), but I'm not sure how to transform this into a triangular array. I've seen a lot in terms of solving, but nothing that will produce simply the upper triangular system.

Does anyone have any recommendations on doing this with one or all of those packages?

Comment: More on RRF in sympy and (not) numpy, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67927403/complex-numbers-matrix-rref-in-python

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above, I noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56501951/1089161) about doing elementary operations on the matrix. That always seems so awkward to do and you might write something to help you work more naturally while you learn how to work with matrices.  Here is a `do` routine that might be such a helper or a suggestion of how to write your own:

```
def do(self, s, i, j, k=1):
    """return self after doing row (`s` starts with 'r') or column (`s` starts with 'c') operation.

    Examples
    ========

    >>> from sympy import Matrix
    >>> Matrix.do = do
    >>> m = Matrix(3, 3, list(range(9))); m
    Matrix([
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8]])

    swap rows 0 and 1

    >>> m.do('rs',0,1)
    Matrix([
    [3, 4, 5],
    [0, 1, 2],
    [6, 7, 8]])

    To row 0, add row 1 multiplied by 2

    >>> m.do('ra',0,1,2)
    Matrix([
    [6, 9, 12],
    [3, 4,  5],
    [6, 7,  8]])

    Multiply row 0 by 2

    >>> m.do('rm',0,2)
    Matrix([
    [0, 2, 4],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8]])

    To operate on columns, replace the 'r' with 'c' in the
    examples above.

    If you want to keep working with the modified matrix
    you can either re-assign the output to the variable used for
    the original matrix (e.g. `m = m.do('rs', 0, 1)`) or make the
    modifications in place by appending an 'i' to `s`:

    >>> m.do('rsi',0,1)
    >>> m
    Matrix([
    [3, 4, 5],
    [0, 1, 2],
    [6, 7, 8]])
    >>> m.do('csi',0,1)
    >>> m
    Matrix([
    [4, 3, 5],
    [1, 0, 2],
    [7, 6, 8]])
    """
    rc, op = s.lower()[:2]
    assert op in 'sma'
    assert rc in 'rc'
    if len(s) > 2:
        # in place
        if rc == 'r':
            if op == 's':
                self.row_swap(i,j)
            elif op == 'm':
                self.row_op(i, lambda v, _: v*j)
            else:
                self.row_op(i, lambda v, _: v + self[j, _]*k)
        else:
            if op == 's':
                self.col_swap(i,j)
            elif op == 'm':
                self.col_op(i, lambda v, _: v*j)
            else:
                self.col_op(i, lambda v, _: v + self[_, j]*k)
    else:
        f = getattr(self, 'elementary_%s_op' % (
            'row' if rc=='r' else 'col'))
        if op == 's':
            return f('n<->m', None, None, i, j)
        elif op == 'a':
            return f('n->n+km', None, k, i, j)
        else:
            return f('n->kn', i, j)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [731]: arr = np.array([[2,-3,0,3],[4,-5,1,7],[2,-1,-3,5]])
```

Your two steps can be done with:

Subtract multiples of 1st row:

```
In [732]: arr -= arr[0,:]*np.array([0,2,1])[:,None]
In [733]: arr
Out[733]: 
array([[ 2, -3,  0,  3],
       [ 0,  1,  1,  1],
       [ 0,  2, -3,  2]])
```

Subtract multiple of 2nd row:

```
In [734]: arr -= arr[1,:]*np.array([0,0,2])[:,None]
In [735]: arr
Out[735]: 
array([[ 2, -3,  0,  3],
       [ 0,  1,  1,  1],
       [ 0,  0, -5,  0]])
```

But I'm not sure this helps you learn linear algebra.  While I worked out how to do it, it's not something we normally do when using `numpy`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you want to do but this is how you can do some basic linear algebra routines in SymPy:

```
In [1]: import sympy as sym

In [2]: M = sym.Matrix([[2,-3,0,3],[4,-5,1,7],[2,-1,-3,5]])

In [3]: M
Out[3]: 
⎡2  -3  0   3⎤
⎢            ⎥
⎢4  -5  1   7⎥
⎢            ⎥
⎣2  -1  -3  5⎦

In [4]: M.echelon_form()
Out[4]: 
⎡2  -3   0   3⎤
⎢             ⎥
⎢0  2    2   2⎥
⎢             ⎥
⎣0  0   -20  0⎦

In [5]: M.rref()
Out[5]: 
⎛⎡1  0  0  3⎤           ⎞
⎜⎢          ⎥           ⎟
⎜⎢0  1  0  1⎥, (0, 1, 2)⎟
⎜⎢          ⎥           ⎟
⎝⎣0  0  1  0⎦           ⎠

In [9]: sym.linsolve(M)
Out[9]: {(3, 1, 0)}
```